# Where is located .ideavimrc file?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I try to find the .ideavimrc file to configure it. All the documentation I can find on Internet refers to ~/.ideavimrc

I can't find it whether I assume it refers to home/ inside Windows Linux Subsystem of the PhpstormProjects/ folder inside the "regular" Windows System.

Where I am suppose to find it?

Comment: Why do you care "Where I am suppose to find it?"? Search the whole local persistence system!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't find it anywhere unless you created it yourself before. File has to be placed in your OS home folder. See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#files for more info